# Unexpected behavior with template type alias in VS2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, language-lawyer, type-alias

The following code compiles with VS15 Community and prints out "Hello".

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using void_template_alias_t = void;

template<typename T>
using Func = std::function<void( T )>;

template<typename T>
using FuncVoid = Func<void_template_alias_t<T>>;

int main()
{
    FuncVoid<void> hello = [] { std::cout << "Hello\n"; };
    hello();
}
```

I think this is not allowed to compile.

I was playing around, the code was a bit more complex. I naively expected this to work, but suddenly realized that this code should not compile because you can't make a `Func<void>` (or am I wrong with this?).

- Did I found a magic workaround?
- Is this a new behavior from the C++14 standard?
- Or is it simply a compiler bug?

Edit: The following more simplified version does not compile.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
using Func = std::function<void( T )>;

int main()
{
    Func<void> hello = [] { std::cout << "Hello\n"; };
    hello();
}
```

- So why is the code above compiling and working as I first expected?
- Is it a correct implementation, if not, how would it look like?

Comment: There is a world of difference between `foo(void)` and `using X = void; foo(X);`. I'd be surprised if other compilers accepted this.

Comment: Oh, I was too sure. The standard states that "The parameter list `(void)` is equivalent to the empty parameter list.", but doesn't specify that `(void)` is literal text. And there is no special grammar production for it, and both g++ and Visual C++ compile `void foo(X)` where `X` is a name for `void`, and they compile the call `foo()`.

Comment: Perhaps I'd better note explicitly, that the interpretation where `(void)` refers to a function where the *type* of the single argument is effectively `void`, and then denotes a function with no arguments, doesn't work well with template code that invokes the function with an argument, i.e. it's impractical. Yet both MSVC and MinGW g++ accept the non-template `foo(My_void)` and call `foo()`. :(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf After [DR 577](http://wg21.link/cwg577), the rule is "A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type `void` is equivalent to an empty parameter list".

Comment: @T.C.: So, this changed in C++14. The DR indicates that the natural reading of C++11 and earlier, as `(void)` being literal text (not allowing `typedef`), is the right one for those versions. Thanks!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So, what is missing to provide an answer to this?

Comment: @Yakk Nothing, so I made one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is it simply a compiler bug?

That. As mentioned by @T.C., [**CWG #577**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#577) is relevant:

> […] there
>   was some concern expressed over the treatment of function templates
>   and member functions of class templates if the C++ rule were changed:
>   for a template parameter `T`, **would a function taking a single parameter
>   of type `T` become a no-parameter function if it were instantiated with
>   `T = void`?**

This is a justified complaint, but unfortunate for you, member functions/member function templates and *type-id*s were affected equally by the resolution:

> A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of **non-dependent type `void`** is equivalent to the an empty parameter list.

thus both your snippets are ill-formed, as the parameter's type is indeed dependent.

---

> Is it a correct implementation, if not, how would it look like?

There is no correct implementation. If you need a function type with an empty parameter list, you'll have to specify that independent from template parameters.

> So why is the code above compiling and working as I first expected?

My best guess: VC++ does the substitution of `void_template_alias_t<T>` *after* assuring that the parameter type is not a *dependent* type "cv `void`", but before making the "`void` -> empty list transformation". However, it's often hard to comprehend how VC++ (or any compiler, for that matter) thinks internally.